# How to store the LatLng variable in Android in an SQL Lite Database for use later?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I am trying to store marker information in an SQL Lite database on an Android device, I am currently converting the `LatLng` variable to a `String` and saving that way.

```
LatLng latLng
coords = latLng.toString();
```

The problem is, and I have tried many things, is converting the `string` back to a `latLng` variable so it can be used again.

Looking into the `LatLng` variable I see it is two `doubles` separated by a comma, I was thinking about splitting the `string` and converting to `doubles` then passing that as a `Latlng` but I don't know how to do this in Android.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: LatLng is a variable in Android, I am using onMapClick and passing it LatLng latlng like sp: public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) LatLng is just two doubles

Comment: you are mistaken as to the function of toString(). look into LatLng, you'll see it has 2 doubles which you can access separately. you ave to store them separately as well

Comment: I saw that njzk2, any idea how I can do this, I ma trying to do that now, I have no luck. Thank you!

Comment: save it in 2 different columns in your base

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

```
LatLng latLng;
Double l1=latlng.latitude;
Double l2=latlng.longitude;
String coordl1 = l1.toString();
String coordl2 = l2.toString();
l1 = Double.parseDouble(coordl1);
l2 = Double.parseDouble(coordl2);


googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(l1, l2))
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(info));
```

So from a Latlng variable to two doubles, to strings,back to doubles and passed to newmarker position and it works!

:)

Answer (score 3):

i save lat and long seperate, maybe this is also a solution for you

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could store the position in the `SharedPreferences`. Here is the [TypedPreferences library](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/TypedPreferences) and the [`LatLngPreference` helper class](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/TypedPreferences/wiki/TypedPreferences-Commons#latlngpreference) to do this easily.